# How to have single HTML file with content from JS based on URL parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Using AngularJS, is it possible to display dynamic content from an external JS datafile without loading separate template HTML files for views? I'm trying to use a single HTML file and populate content from the JS datafile dynamically based on URL query parameters. 
For example:

website.com/index.html?product=product01
website.com/index.html?product=product02
website.com/index.html?product=product03

I'm having trouble finding a solution for this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The classical solution is to generate view HTML template on server side before serving it to the client.
The "AngularJS" solution is to use AngularJS templating system using controllers ou directives scope.

Comment: Not only it is possible, but that's the whole point of AngularJS. But that would be more like website.com/product/product01

Comment: Just inject `$routeParams` in your controller and read the `product` value. Then, according to `product` just load any JSON, or whatever it is with the `$http` AngularJS service for example and populate some variable. Create a template to display that variable and you're done. If you have some code to start with it would be easier to answer.

Comment: That's what I'm hoping for. With this unique situation I'm forced to depend on the URL parameters to tell the controller which data to pull from the JS file and I have to use the index.html?product=product01 structure.

Answer (score 0):

Please check sources of "UI Bootstrap" collection of directives, all templates are declared in JS file and stored in template cache on module load.
http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Open "ui-bootstrap-tpls.js" file, look for "template/timepicker" string inside it for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use angular ui router dependency to work around state related issues.

Inject this module by including script  by

```
 angular.module("myApp", ['ui.router']);
```

and then in configuration of app, return different controllers based on the query parameters. Note the url which has "?"

```
  angular.module("myApp")
  .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider',
   function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
      $stateProvider
        .state('index.html', {
      url: "/index.html?product"
      controller: function ($stateParams) {
       //get corresponding controller
       var ctrlName = $stateParams.type + "Product";
       //product1 , product2 etc.
       return ctrlName;
      }
    })
 }]);
```